# How to change the background color of a row in RDLC report on mouse over?

Tags: row, mouseover, rdlc, background-color, highlight

### How to change the background color of a row in RDLC report on mouse over?

set background color on mouse over. To identify rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## $('table:contains("**ID**"):last tr') is to get the report table. "ID" is used to find out the report table from the form.

[image: Screen shot. Text marked in red round is used to find the Report table]

**JQuery**

```
function ColorRow() {
        $('table:contains("ID"):last tr').addClass('trrr');
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.trrr:hover {
        background-color: orange;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**Code in ASPX.CS page Report viewer Load Event (call the JQuery Function)**

Note: Must add below code, other wise it will not work in all report pages (just in one page). Also repeat table column header in each page.

```
 protected void ReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ColorRow", "ColorRow();", true);

    }
```